# Ubuntu not connecting after update to 17.04. Previous answers not working

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

I've updated from 16.04 LTS and connections don't work. Wifi nor Ethernet.
I've tried previous/similar answers; changing IPv4 Settings--> DNS Servers, dissabling dnsmasq from NetworkManager.conf file. In fact dnsmasq was not even installed.
Moreover running a virtualpc won't work either.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Backing up and installing from scratch probably takes less time than troubleshooting the failed upgrade.

Comment: It's not the best option as we have some restrictions to fit a specific cluster. And it has data from multiple users that have already gone. In the worst case I'll have to do it. Thanks!

Comment: Finally reinstalling from a live-USB without formatting fixed the issue. Thanks @MichaelBay

Comment: Solved is what matters :) System wide online upgrades (release upgrades) can fail for any number of reasons and it's generally easier and faster to reinstall even in your particular scenario (and you should have backups anyway).